# How to measure layout performance effectively and easily?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0, systrace, hierarchyviewer

Due to this [article](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer) Hierarchy Viewer is deprecated. Now you can use [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) for analyzing your layout. But Layout Inspector does **not** measure. You can look for alerts due to layout performance by using [systrace](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html?m=1) but it does not show you how to view layout hierarchy tree and looking at layout, measure and draw time. In Hierarchy Viewer you could do that. But now you seem to code something with [Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener).

I don't want to code anything for measuring layout performance. This [article](http://dmtracedump) show us that we can use dmtracedump. But honestly I don't know how to do that for drawing such a [tree view](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/images/tracedump.png):

[image]

So can you tell me a way to measure layout hierarchy performance without any coding? Maybe an explanation how to call dmtracedump for doing so?

Or is dmtracedump just for displaying a trace file in human readable form? So how to **create** the trace file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out that Android Studio 3.2 Preview Version has an improved Profiler where you can capture the whole Method Stack. There you can find the View methods called measure(), layout () and draw().